# Recreate DynamoDB tables used in AWS AppSync

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have an AWS AppSync API in dev using DataStore backed by DynamoDB tables. I have deleted all of the tables from Dynamo DB and was hoping AppSync could recreate them but that does not seem to be the case.  Does anyone know of a way to regenerate the DynamoDB tables?  My AppSync API Data Sources are still pointing to those tables even though they no longer exist.  When I attempt to delete the Data Sources, it states they are tied to functions so they cannot be deleted.  There are hundreds of functions that would need to be deleted.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: How were the tables created in the first place? What automation did you use? Generally you would not delete resources outside of your automation - instead you would modify the automation and re-deploy.

Comment: I used the amplify cli, but it does not seem to want to recreate anything

Comment: How did you delete the tables? Outside of amplify cli? These automation tools maintain state of your application. If you delete resources outside of its control, it doesn't know about it, and it won't fix it.

Comment: Yes I knew it would not know about it when I deleted them.  I was hoping that the logic it used to originally create the tables would check to see if they exist, and if not, create them.  I ended up just deleting the API category from my project and recreating it.

Comment: I would typically comment out the tables (and any dependent references) in my templates, re-deploy, then uncomment them, then re-deploy.

Answer (score 0):

If you accidentally deleted I found a way I don't know wheather it is recommended or not go to app sync page select your project click data sources there you can find tables that are been created by amplify use that table name you won't see that error again.